# Cannot resolve symbol "ipfs' android

Tags: ipfs, java, android

Hello i am trying to send some files from android to IPFS.I am following this [***article***](https://medium.com/coinmonks/setting-up-ipfs-with-android-sdk-a3f621125e47) on medium but can't import packages that are required

```
`
import io.ipfs.api.IPFS;
import io.ipfs.api.MerkleNode;
import io.ipfs.api.NamedStreamable;
import io.ipfs.multiaddr.MultiAddress;`.
```

i am getting Cannot resolve symbol "'ipfs'" error.
I added `implementation group: 'com.github.ipfs', name: 'java-ipfs-http-client', version: 'v1.3.3'` 
to my app.gradle as it's statded in this article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this
need to put maven `{ url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to settings.gradle